# Algorithms for "shortening" strings?

Tags: string, algorithm

I am looking for elegant ways to "shorten" the (user provided) names of object. More precisely:

- my users can enter free text (used as "name" of some object), they can use up to 64 chars (including whitespaces, punctuation marks, ...)
- in addition to that "long" name; we also have a "reduced" name (exactly 8 characters); required for some legacy interface

Now I am looking for thoughts on how to generate these "reduced" names, based on the 64-char name.

With "elegant" I am wondering about any useful ideas that "might" allow the user to recognize something with value within the shortened string.
Like, if the name is "Production Test Item A5"; then maybe "PTIA5" might (or might not) tell the user something useful.

Comment: There are far more 64 character words than 8 character words,  so you will end up with collisions.  The DOS approach was to truncate and append a counter.

Comment: if your reduced name can contain same characters as your the long one, why not just randomly pick indexes and remove characters at these indexes? I mean why should it be elegant if it's a "free" text as you said?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply a substring method to the long version, trim it, in case there are any whitespace characters at the end, optionally remove any special characters from the very end (such as dashes) and finally add a dot, in case you want to indicate your abbreviation that way.

Just a quick hack to get you started:

```
  String longVersion = "Aswaghtde-5d";

  // Get substring 0..8 characters
  String shortVersion = longVersion.substring(0, (longVersion.length() < 8 ? longVersion.length() : 8));

  // Remove whitespace characters from end of String
  shortVersion = shortVersion.trim();

  // Remove any non-characters from end of String
  shortVersion = shortVersion.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]+$", "");

  // Add dot to end
  shortVersion = shortVersion.substring(0, (shortVersion.length() < 8 ? shortVersion.length() : shortVersion.length() - 1)) + ".";

  System.out.println(shortVersion);
```

Answer (score 2):

I needed to shorten names to function as column names in a database. Ideally, the names should be recognizable for users. I set up a dictionary of patterns for commonly occuring words with corresponding "abbreviations".  This was applied ONLY to those names which were over the limit of 30 characters.

Comment: Nice idea, but the problem is that we would have absolutely no control about the domain, or anything here. So coming up with a reasonable dictionary is nor really a solution (for us). But I appreciate the idea, and hey, welcome to upvote levels ;-)